# How do I dynamically update the shape of tf.ones_like()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, reshape

I'm having a trouble with dimensions of my weight matrices in tensorflow.

```
#outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [batch_size, seq_length, num_classes])

outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, seq_length, num_classes])

output_dim = outputs.get_shape().as_list()

weights = tf.ones([output_dim[0], seq_length], tf.int32) #TODO: change the dimension

sequence_loss = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits=outputs, targets=Y, weights=weights)
```

So, I have a batch_size that changes at the last epoch, and the dimension of the weights cause trouble when it comes to the last epoch.

the 
    `weights = tf.ones([output_dim[0], seq_length], tf.int32)` 
causes the following error:

```
"Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: %s" % s)
ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?, 25)
```

How would you solve this problem? I tried using `tf.ones_like(outputs)` but that didn't seem to work, and `tf.ones` appears to require a fixed value as its dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tf.fill`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill), which supports dynamic shape:

```py
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 25, 10])
b = tf.fill(tf.shape(a)[:-1], 1)  # shape=[None, 25]

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(b, feed_dict={a: np.zeros([10, 25, 10])}))

# Prints:
# [[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong but it says there is an error in the sequence_loss line. It says its trying to convert from dtype float32 to dtype int32 and it's invalid. I have never come across this sort of issue before.

Comment: Fill with `1.0` if you need a float type.